# Whole Structure is being replaced with the last pointer Value

Tags: structure

In my program I have used an array of pointers as a structure variable to get first name and second name from the user.

The following is my function call statement:

```
ret_val = update_person(&ptr_person[person_index],f_name,s_name);
```

where `ptr_person[SIZE]` is a pointer variable and `f_name` and `s_name` are character array variables.

The following is my function definition where `name_ret` is `int`:

```
name_ret update_person(person_name_et **person,char *first_arg,char *second_arg)
{

        int val = SUCCESS, val1 = SUCCESS,val2= SUCCESS;     
        int f_len = sizeof(first_arg);
        int s_len = sizeof(second_arg);
        val2 = remove_newline(first_arg);
        val1 = remove_newline(second_arg);
        val = allocate_person(person, f_len, s_len);
        if((val && val1) == SUCCESS)
        {   
                (*person)->first_name = first_arg;
                (*person)->second_name = second_arg;
                return SUCCESS;
        }
        else
        {
        return FAILURE;
      }
}
```

The problem in the code is it works fine at the instance but when the function is called next iteration the `ptr_Person[0]` is replaced with `ptr_person[1]` and if we have 5 instances then all the 5 variables are replaced by the last values.

Comment: please add proper code formatting while you add code.

Comment: Largely formatting...

Comment: I need a solution for this pls any one help me